# Python pymssql connection string using variables

Tags: python, sql-server, variables

I'm writing a script that connects to MSSQL DB using pymssql module. 
I couldn't find a way to make the connect method to work using variables.

This works:

```
a = pymssql.connect(host='sqlserver', port=3183,user='admin',password='pass',database='master')
```

This does not (b1-5 are variables):

```
a = pymssql.connect(b1,b2,b3 b4,b5)
(Like shown in first example in www.pymssql.org/en/latest/pymssql_examples.html)
```

I'm getting this error:

> File "pymssql.pyx", line 636 in pymssql. connect (pymssql. c:10178)
>   pymssql.OperationalError: (20009, 'DB-Lib error message 20009,severity
>   9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not
>   exist\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error (10035)\n')

The database is fine, I can manually log in and the literal connection string works. 
my variables (b1-5) include no single nor double quotes.
When I'm using single quotes I'm getting

> Connection to database failed for an unknown reason.

Do you have an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You should write:

```
a = pymssql.connect(host=b1, port=b2,user=b3,password=b4,database=b5)
```

Where *b1* is actually a HOST, *b2* is a PORT, and so on...

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried. Got the same error as the first one I mentioned.

Comment: I look through pymssql manual, the port variable should be string, is it string in your case?

Comment: It is. But again, no quotes of any kind.

Comment: please show part of code where are you assign values to variables

Comment: b1="sqlserver",  b2="3183",  b3="admin",  b4="pass",  b5 = "master"